# Low poly models for buildings creation

Tags: game-engine, geometry, retopology, polycount, remesh

**[INTRO]:**
I'm currently working on a project that includes an extensive library of high poly building models. The web engine in which we are planning to operate them seems not to handle such a large amount of complex geometry, so low poly models for "Bake Selected to Active" have to be made.

The quality of geometry those models should have is approximately the same as shown on the images below: respectively, "Figure 1" is the original model, "Figure 2" is low poly. While all significant (large) elements of the facade should be preserved, small ones (e.g. windows, shallow depressions, some sorts of mosaics, etc.) are ignored in terms of geometry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**[THE PROBLEM]:**
While talking about simple and repeating buildings, it's easy to do low polys mannually: I can just make one model and copy it for all buildings of the same type.
The problem is that the library contains a large number of unique and much more complicated buildings.
Here's an example of complicated building I'm definitely going to have troubles with: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mxEa5jaJ5__obxidG_2YZnwNTbRUcYWH/view?usp=sharing

**[THE QUESTION]:**
So, is there any way to "automatize" the process of low poly modeling or at least to make it a little bit more easier for hard surface objects?
Saying ANY here I mean literaly anything: a plugin (paid ones are just fine too), some Blender tricks I might have missed, a combination of those – anything, any idea you have.

I clearely realize that even after using the most "smart" plugin, there will still be a lot improvements to final geeometry, but if it's somehow possible to at least save time on creating basic forms of the buildings without that crazy pixelhunting for main verticles – that'll be great.

**[MY ATTEMPTS]:**
What I've tried already but with no luck:

- Shrinkwrap a highpoly cube or same-formed
  parallelepiped on the target model;
- Remesh target model using Blocks;
- Remesh target model using Voxels and then Decimate;
- Decimate target model by Seams;
- Use AssetsGen plugin.

If anyone have any ideas on that kind of context, please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately that question really comes into the "What not to ask" section of https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic so I'd say it was off-topic here as it's really too vague for a definitive answer. You might have better luck asking at https://blenderartists.org/.